# PHP code inside of HTML email not working

Tags: php, html

Trying to test send a HTML email to myself using PHP but the PHP code inside the HTML does not work and I don't know why. Sorry if I'm not very clear, I'm quite new to this

```
<?php 

$ccode = rand(1000, 9999);
$to = "example@gmail.com";
$from = "example2@gmail.com";
$subject = "Confirmation Code";
echo $ccode;

//begin of HTML message 
$message = '<html>
             <head>
              <title> Confirmation Code</title>
             </head>
               <body style="background-color:#004d4d">
                <div style= "text-align:center"> <img src="example.png" alt="Logo" width="300" height="300" align="top;center"> </div>
                <h1 style="font-family:verdana; color:white; text-align:center"> This is your confirmation code:  </h1>
                <p style= "text-align:center;font-size:400%;color:#009999; font-family:arial"> 
               <b> 

                //code that isn't working
               <?php 

                $ccode = rand(1000, 9999); 
                echo $ccode; 

                ?> 
              </b>
              </p>
              <p style= "text-align:center; font-family:verdana; color:white"> Please enter this code into the application. </p>
              </body>
              </html>';
              //end of message 
$headers  = "From: $from\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

// now lets send the email. 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 

echo "Message has been sent....!"; 
?>
```

The email sends as usual but the PHP part inside the email does not work and prints "$ccode" instead.

I would appreciate any kind of help or advice on this thank you!

Comment: you are already inside php tags, no need to open them again

Comment: have your server PHP configured?

Comment: @PraneethNidarshan Since this is a PHP script and OP said the mail gets sent I guess Yes

Answer (score 4):

```
$message = '<html>
         ...
          </html>';
          //end of message
```

This is a string, the code within is also considered text. You could declare your variable before assigning the string to $message. I.e.:

```
<?php 
$ccode = rand(1000, 9999); 
$message = '<html>
         <head>
          <title> Confirmation Code</title>
         </head>
           <body style="background-color:#004d4d">
            <div style= "text-align:center"> <img src="example.png" alt="Logo" width="300" height="300" align="top;center"> </div>
            <h1 style="font-family:verdana; color:white; text-align:center"> This is your confirmation code:  </h1>
            <p style= "text-align:center;font-size:400%;color:#009999; font-family:arial"> 
           <b>'.
          $ccode .
          '</b>
          </p>
          <p style= "text-align:center; font-family:verdana; color:white"> Please enter this code into the application. </p>
          </body>
          </html>';
          //end of message
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't put a code php when you try to declare the variable $message

but you can do a concatenation with another variable which you have declared from the beginning

> so you can either do this

```
      <?php 
      $ccode = rand(1000, 9999);
      $message = '<html> other balises' . $ccode . 'some other balises</html>';
      ?>
```

> or with double cote (")

```
      <?php 
      $ccode = rand(1000, 9999);
      $message = "<html> other balises {$ccode}  some other balises</html>";
      ?>
```

> or the last solution

```
      <?php 
      $message = "<html> other balises";
      $ccode = rand(1000, 9999);
      $message .= $ccode;
      $message = "some other balises</html>";          
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem come with your `$message` variable.

It's a string, so you can not use the open php block code here.

It should be:

`$message = '... <html code>' . $ccode . '... <other html code>';`

Hope this help!